# Create numpy datetime format from arrays and single values for year, month and day

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I have two datasets, a year and a month. Both are in masked arrays. I also have an observation day which is always 15. I would like to create a masked array with datetimes based on these three values.

Simply using:

```
obs_Date = np.datetime64(year, month, 15)
```

Does not seem to be a thing. How would I create a datetime format based on the year and month arrays and the date value I have?

Comment: what do you mean by *numpy datetime format*? Should the result be a numpy array with numpy datetime data type?

Comment: It should be an array with datetime data types yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[numpy datetime](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html) constructs a bit different than [Python datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), e.g. from an ISO-format string like

```
import numpy.ma as ma

years = ma.array([2020, 2021, 2022], mask=[0,1,0])
months = ma.array([1, 3, 7], mask=[0,1,0])
day=15

# masks must be identical
assert (years.mask == months.mask).all()

dates = ma.array(
    [f'{y}-{m:02d}-{day}' for y, m in zip(years.data, months.data)],
    dtype='datetime64[D]',
    mask=years.mask
    )

# dates
# masked_array(data=[datetime.date(2020, 1, 15), --,
#                    datetime.date(2022, 7, 15)],
#              mask=[False,  True, False],
#        fill_value=numpy.datetime64('NaT'),
#             dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

---

Another option using [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), keeping the masked values as `NaT` (not-a-time):

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.to_datetime(
            pd.DataFrame({'year': years, 'month': months, 'day': [day]*years.size})
            )

# dates
# 0   2020-01-15
# 1          NaT
# 2   2022-07-15
# dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you, the second option worked  flawlessly.

Comment: @B.Quaink if you happen to work with pandas anyway, that would also be my suggestion to use since it's much more clear/readable